# FirebaseStorage works on "flutter run --release --web-renderer canvaskit" but not when it is hosted with "flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit "

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I need to upload fotos via an wep app to firebase storage. For some reason, it works on my computer (local) when I use "flutter run --release --web-renderer canvaskit" but not on my server, I tried different, when I build it with "flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit" and deploy it, it wont work.

The code:

```
FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref('$id/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid}_1.png')
        .putData(_imageFile!);
```